# Python: Caesar cipher ASCII code in a function

Tags: python, list, int, ascii

I need to define a function, `encrypt1`, that takes a list of integers as the input and returns a string consisting of their corresponding characters in ASCII.

This is what I coded and I do not understand why it does not work.

```
def ascii2string(L): 
  List = L[0]
  ''join(chr(i) for i in List)
  return i
```

It just comes with an error:

> int object is not iterable

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message or traceback? Please note that `i` is the non-iterable item.

Comment: If `List` is a list of integers, `L` is an integer; you can't iterate over it. `''join` is a syntax error, needs a dot. `return i` is returning the wrong thing, while the result of the `join` is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same using append also.

```
def ascii2string(L): 
asc = []
for i in L: asc.append(chr(i))
print(asc)

L =[89,79,101] #Example
ascii2string(L)
```

> Output : ['Y', 'O', 'e']